# translate php website without extrernalizing resources

Tags: php

I have a php site that mixes html and php.
ex:

```
<html>
hello <?=$username?>
```

I need infact to keep texts are they are. I do not want a classical solution such as that consits of creating reosurce strings and replace them such as:

```
<html>
<?=echo $helloString?> <?=$username?>
```

Infact a kind of "autoscript" that will replace all text resources at run time. So I keep the existing site and just add some script at begin.

```
<? include("translation_module.php?")?>
<html>
hello <?=$username?>
```

and this translation_module.php will replace "hello" to "bonjour".

Any clue to achieve that ?

**I don't care about grammer, currencies, plurial problems.**

- I guess it should work like google translate: it should execute itself, and translate then output texts and finally printout the result (of course I have no idea how it does it, how it handles $GET, $POST, $SESSION variables...)

Thanks

Comment: What you want is not possible

Comment: It most likely can't be done without running all output through a filter, such as Google translate, since you in no way indicate which texts should be translated and which one should be left alone, such as $username. Furthermore, you'll run into problems with plural, currencies etc.

Comment: No pains, no gains. Nobody said i18n was easy.

Comment: To achieve literally what you're asking, you need to: use an HTML parser and go through the files, filtering out the PHP tags ***or*** use the PHP parser to go through the files and filter out the HTML. What you're left with is, hopefully, the raw text. Then try to break that text down into meaningful, translatable parts. This step is really really hard. Separating on words is easy, but will leave you with nonsensical translations. Separating on sentences can be tricky, especially with variables inside. Once you have that though, simply substitute the parts. Overall: it's the wrong approach.

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically this might be possible for such simple cases, but it's not going to work in practice. What about strings that contain injected variables and yet still have to be translated? For example:

```
You have <?= $inboxCount?> messages in your inbox
```

This cannot be translated to any language where the grammar mandates that e.g. "messages" must appear before the number. And keep in mind that it's only a simple off-the-top example; anyone that has spent any amount of time working with i18n will tell you that if you want a proper solution you have to externalize *all the strings*, *independently of one another*.

Comment: Even theoretically it's barely possible. Translation relies on the context. And OP doesn't want to bring any additional translation context to his files.

Comment: @zerkms: True... "might be" is more appropriate.

Comment: well there are just 2 strings !
"You have" -> "Vous avez"
"messages in your box" -> "messages dans votre boite"

It works perfectly

Comment: @user300675: It works *in french*. Try chinese. As I said, if you have spent any amount of time doing i18n you know that this won't work (in the general case). You don't have to believe me; look at how all PHP frameworks do it. There's a reason.

Comment: @user ...and even if you're only concerned about French and English, I'm 100% sure you will find cases where it simply does not translate 1:1 like that. If you think otherwise you have no idea about human languages.

Answer (score 0):

Grammar wise, its not going to work, cause some sentances are just to complicated to propperly translate in the main language through a translator, and as stated by @Jon, the grammar mandates sometimes to have values different placed.

What i would suggest you do is, you write or translate it your main content in multiple languages, and when the user specifies a languages you have your site just jump over, MAIN content wise. I doubt if you have a forum, you want everybody to make their post in (for example) three languages.

Some things you migth have to do with an if else statement as well, because of the grammer.

Answer (score -2):

You could achieve this by use somes Objects.

```
<?
class LocalizationFR{

     public function getHelloMessage(){
          return "bonjour";
     }
}

class LocalizationEN{

     public function  getHelloMessage(){
              return "Hello";
     }
}

class Localization{

     public function setHelloMessage(){
          array_push('messages', array('locale' => 'fr', 'message' => LocalizationFR::getHelloMessage()));
          array_push('messages', array('locale' => 'en', 'message' => LocalizationEN::getHelloMessage()));
     }

     public static function getHelloMessage($locale){
          return $this->messages[$locale];
     }

    }
```

And, in your code, just

```
<?php echo Localization::getHelloMessage('fr'); ?>
```

Right ?

Comment: And, if you need to translate in many languages, don't forget to use a replacement pattern like %s to do a [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.sprintf.php) and then, you could translate you'r website to the entire languages availlable

Comment: Hello, exactly the contrary to what I try to achieve !